# How to update any of the on-chain attribute of a NFT in Solana?

Tags: metaplex

I have an NFT on Solana and I would like to update any of the one attributes that is defined in the Token Metadata standard.

Comment: I would add clarity on whether you mean a property on the NFT token (on-chain data) or an attribute that NFTs can add to describe it (off-chain data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the metadata of the NFT the **@metaplex/js** SDK can be used it has functions which can do that for example :-

this piece of code updates the on-chain name of the NFT

```
const { nft: updatedNft } = await metaplex
.nfts()
.update(nft, { name: "My Updated Name" })
.run();
```

to update the off-chain url data + the onchain data the @metaplex/js SDK provides a function that does that

```
const { uri: newUri } = await metaplex
.nfts()
.uploadMetadata({
    ...nft.json,
    name: "My Updated Metadata Name",
    description: "My Updated Metadata Description",
})
.run();
```

If there is something that needs to be done low level that there is the low level SDK provided by metaplex for such interactions **@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata**

for example the code here constructs the instruction and the transaction for updating an NFT and sends it to the Solana Blockchain

```
const updated_data: DataV2 = {
name: "DeGods",
symbol: "DG",
uri: "https://metadata.degods.com/g/4924.json",
sellerFeeBasisPoints: 1000,
creators: [
  {
    address: new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
      "HXSm9FhAa7BJ5UK53iBqj1yF9KgMBqNBySYcgduX5smf"
    ),
    verified: false,
    share: 0,
  },
  {
    address: wallet.publicKey,
    verified: false,
    share: 100,
  },
],
collection: null,
uses: null,
};
const accounts:UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts = {
metadata: metadatakey,
updateAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
}

const args:UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionArgs = {
updateMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
  data: updated_data,
  updateAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
  primarySaleHappened: true,
  isMutable: true,
}
}

const updateMetadataAccount = createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction(
accounts,
args
);
const transaction = new anchor.web3.Transaction()
transaction.add(updateMetadataAccount);
const {blockhash} = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTx.serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Quick note: this answer focuses on updating the Metadata account which stores the data struct on chain. Find more information in the [Metaplex docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts#metadata).*

To update the NFT token via the command line, [Metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/update.html) is a great tool built by a developer at Metaplex.

Before making any changes, it is recommended you take the advice posted in the Metaboss docs:

> Make sure you understand how the Metaplex Metadata Data struct works and how this (update NFT) command will affect your NFT. Always test on devnet before running on mainnet.

To update the NFT data struct via Metaboss, first install the script linked on the front page of the Metaboss docs.

As of v0.8.0, the following command can be used to update the NFT with a file from your local machine:

`metaboss update data --keypair <PATH_TO_KEYPAIR> --account <MINT_ACCOUNT> --new-data-file <PATH_TO_NEW_DATA_FILE>`

- `<PATH_TO_KEYPAIR>` is the wallet that has `update authority` on the NFT.
- `<MINT_ACCOUNT>` is the token account address.
- `<PATH_TO_NEW_DATA_FILE>` is a valid JSON file (see example below) with the full data expected to be on the token when the update completes.

```
{
    "name": "FerrisCrab #4",
    "symbol": "FERRIS",
    "uri": "https://arweave.net/N36gZYJ6PEH8OE11i0MppIbPG4VXKV4iuQw1zaq3rls",
    "seller_fee_basis_points": 100,
    "creators": [
        {
            "address": "<YOUR_CANDY_MACHINE_ID>",
            "verified": true,
            "share": 0
        },
        {
            "address": "<KEYPAIR_CREATOR>",
            "verified": true,
            "share": 50
        },
        {
            "address": "42NevAWA6A8m9prDvZRUYReQmhNC3NtSZQNFUppPJDRB",
            "verified": false,
            "share": 50
        }
    ]
}
```